# Is there a more efficient way to read the data from the web?

Tags: java, performance, url, web, readline

I am making an application that reads "real-time" stock tick data from a website that prints the data in txt format.

- All I'm concerned about is the last line
- I have a timer event go off ever 1/4 of a second to the URL and read the data.
- Right now this takes about 10 seconds the first time and then 4 seconds each time after that.
- I am wondering/hoping there is a better way to read from the stream and or get the data from the web.

This is how I am getting the data from the web

```
    URL website = new URL("www.somesite.com/blah.php?csv_format=txt");
    isr = new InputStreamReader(website.openStream());
```

This is how read the data

- I read through the ENTIRE set of data from start to finish until I reach the end
- I save the last line in some variable and use that information for my line graph.
- I stopped using readLine() and moved to using character arrays to see if that sped things up.

This is my most recent try (an attempt to keep it simple as possible)

```
    int n = 0;
    while (n != -1) {
        n = isr.read(buffer, 0, 8192);
    }
```

Comment: Your last try will break one day, as you can end up with an incomplete last line (imagine it starts just at offset 8190). Using two buffers would do (as long as the line doesn't exceed the buffer length).

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't ever really implement it like that but I figured that this way might be the quickest and all I was interested in was timing it. Before I was using two buffers named buffer and lineBuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot easier to use the HTTP protocol in order to have better control on the boundaries of your requests and the responses. Have a look at HTTPUrlConnection. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) is a nice sample.

EDIT:

After reviewing in detail the requirements (see comments), I suggested an alternate approach by using Spark streaming [api](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) in order to consume "stock tick data".

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, i'll give that a try. I did see that before but when I looked at the documentation it didn't look like it did what I wanted.

Comment: That isn't what I really wanted from research it seems that I want something that will do server-side pushing of data, basically have a long term connection with a data stream (which the site I am using is a plain text stream) and have it consistently send data every time it receives it. I believe in chunks. My research has lead me to SSE with HTML5 and or websockets. Websockets sounds more complicated because all I want is to receive data not send and receive so I am trying to figure out how to embed javascript into java.

Comment: to be honest, web sockets are very easy to use (I've done an app using Wildfly). What are your consistency requieremnts for the data stream? If it's going to be sound or video (or even a file sharing project such as P2P), I strongly recommend to use DatagramSocket (UDP protocol).

Comment: Its a plain text data stream, I am not sure what you mean by consistency requirements. It is stock tick data so it is only generating data from 9:30 - 4:30 EST but I am graphing/analyzing the data in my program.

Comment: AHH! then you should really have a look to Spark streaming API. I've used ut as well and is fairly easy to learn. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: ra2085, I am messing with spark and I have most of it figured out, I am just trying to figure out how to use it with the website I am getting the information from. I have the URL of it... I was thinking I should use socketTextStream but I believe I don't fully understand how that works. should I be trying to get the data a different way?

Comment: Well, if none of the existent (offered) adapters work for you, then you should implement your own data stream listener. Have a look here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html

Comment: your source "Stock tick data" must be published in a certain way, meaning protocol, delimiters, etc. So I strongly recommend to use a custom receiver.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I saw actorStream and thought that is maybe what I had to use. I've been reading the API but its kinda vague or maybe I just don't have enough knowledge and/or experience in this area. So the general jist of it is to create a javaStreamingContext which can be used to create a type of DStream. You then create a receiver in order to receive the data in and do what you wish with? I am about to read the link you provided to understand where a custom listener would come into play but otherwise you have been so much help. How do I give you rep?

Comment: Next to the answer will be 2 arrows and a number of votes. Just vote up the answer (includes all this messages). BTW, once you implement a reciever, then it will "read" data into your Streaming Context (using distributed objects). This context is nothing more than a "distributed" way of managing chunks of data. This is the main characteristic of spark, meaning you can scale up and out of a server to manage huge amounts of data (in your specific scenario, real-time data stream).